# Rendering a row of checkboxes in a table in React

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I am trying to render a row of checkboxes in a table for every ingredient present in an array of ingredients. The problem I am facing is that when I check a checkbox for a particular ingredient, all the checkboxes of for all the ingredients get checked. Can anyone help me? I am attaching the JSON for the meal as well as my solution in the code snippet. any help would be highly appreciated.

```
const   ItemDetails = (props) => {

    const [MealDetails, setMEalDetails] = useState([{id:'',name:'',ingredients:[]}]);
    const [checkedOne, setCheckedOne] = useState(false);
    const [checkedTwo, setCheckedTwo] = useState(false);
    const [checkedThree, setCheckedThree] = useState(false);

    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchMealDetails = async () =>{
            const getMeal = await fetch(""+`${props.mealId}`);
            const Meal = [];
            const getMealresponse = await getMeal.json();
            Meal.push(getMealresponse)
        
            setMEalDetails(Meal);
            console.log(getMealresponse)
            console.log(Meal);
        }

    fetchMealDetails()},[])

    
   const handleChangeOne = (event,) => {
     
        setCheckedOne((prevVal,index) => !prevVal);
        setCheckedTwo(false);
        setCheckedThree(false);}
  
     
   

    return(
            <div className={classes.itemDetailContainer} >
                        <div className={classes.topRow}>
                            <h1>{MealDetails[0].name}</h1>
                            <h3><i>Quality Score: </i>100%</h3>
                            <h3><i>Price: </i>$200</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div className={classes.IngredientsTable}>
                            <table className={classes.table}>
                            <tr className={classes.tr}>
                                <th className={classes.th}>Ingredients:</th>
                                <th className={classes.th}>low</th>
                                <th className={classes.th}>Medium</th>
                                <th className={classes.th}>High</th>
                            </tr>
                            {
                                MealDetails[0].ingredients.map(
                                        (ingredient,index) =>{
                                            return( 
                                                <tr key={index}>
                                                    <td className={classes.th} >{ingredient.name}</td>
                                                    {ingredient.options.map(
                                                       (entry,index) =>
                                                        {return  <td>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" value={entry.quality} key={index} id={index} checked={checkedOne} onChange={handleChangeOne} /> 
                                                        </td>}    
                                                    )}
                                                </tr>                                                                                             
                                                
                                                
                                            )
                                        }
                                )
                            }
                               
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div className={classes.ButtonContainer}>
                        <Button value="Close" onClick={props.onClick}  />
                        <Button value="Add to Cart" onClick={props.onClick} />
                        </div>
                        
             </div>
    
    )
}

export default ItemDetails;
```

```
Array(1)
0
: 
id
: 
1
ingredients
: 
Array(2)
0
: 
groups
: 
(2) ['vegan', 'vegetarian']
name
: 
"Rice"
options
: 
Array(3)
0
: 
name
: 
"Long grain white rice"
per_amount
: 
"kilogram"
price
: 
3
quality
: 
"high"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
1
: 
{name: 'Medium grain brown rice', quality: 'medium', price: 2, per_amount: 'kilogram'}
2
: 
{name: 'Quick cooking white rice', quality: 'low', price: 1.5, per_amount: 'kilogram'}
length
: 
3
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
quantity
: 
120
quantity_type
: 
"gram"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
1
: 
{name: 'Chicken', options: Array(3), quantity: 85, quantity_type: 'gram'}
length
: 
2
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
name
: 
"Rice and chicken bowl"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
length
: 
1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `checkOne` variable is used for all the checkboxes. You need to give different variables for each checkbox. **I think** you can achieve this by passing a parent index `<input type="checkbox" value={entry.quality} key={subIndex} id={index} checked={checkedOne[index]} onChange={handleChangeOne(index)} />` and you need to modify your `const handleChangeOne = (index) => (event)`

Comment: Thank you for the response. What you are saying is does work but it again goes back to the initial problem. What I wanted to achieve was that when somebody presses one checkbox so the other checkboxes are unchecked automatically. with the solution, you provided the already checked checkboxes remain checked when an unchecked checked box is checked.

Comment: you can set all the variables to `false` and make it true to the current checked variables in the `const handleChangeOne = (index) => (event)`